# Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file,the tool couldn't find it

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, android-launcher

I used flutter flavor and I can't run but it run from terminal using this type of command:

```
flutter run --flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart
```

When I run using android studio run button then show this exception, which I write below:

Exception: Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\Users\ranak\StudioProjects\bachelor_flat\build, but the tool couldn't find it.

[image] here is my app-build.gradle file

Answer (score 7):

Click on the dropdown near the run button and select `Edit Configurations`, then write `--flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart` or anything you want in the `Additional run args` text field.

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: run configaration already in main_prod.dart selected

Comment: Then just add `--flavor prod` to "Additional run args" of "Edit Configurations"

Comment: I did the same as Kasymbek R. Tashbaev, but still I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to get it to work

```
flutter pub cache clean       
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

just be sure ONE device is connected to android studio , then flutter clean and run.